# Formatar resultado de uma divisão de inteiros

Tags: java, variáveis

Tenho o seguinte codigo em JAVA:

```
private int metros = 1500, minutos = 60;

    System.out.println("Distância em km = "+(metros/1000));

    System.out.println("Tempo em horas = "+(minutoa/60));
```

No entanto o que é exibido após a execução disso é 1km e eu queria que ele imprimisse na tela o valor formatado ex: "1,5 km" sem a necessidade de ter que criar uma variável double, isto é, se for possível.

Esse mesmo problema se aplica a horas, por exemplo, quando pesso para dividir **90 min** ele deveria me retornar **1 e 30 min** da sobra, ao invés disso me retorna 1 hora.

Comment: Sem converter não tem jeito, 1,5 é um float, se ao menos um dos operandos não for um float ou double, sua divisão nunca apresentará casas decimais, não fazendo uso de divisão de inteiros.

Comment: São dois problemas distintos, seria interessante apresentar o trecho do código do segundo problema também.

Comment: @diegofm obrigado! Pelo visto terei que criar uma variável... Mas e quanto a formatação do tempo, tem como eu fazer isso?

Comment: Não tem que criar variável, só tem que converter.

Comment: Uma solução simples seria: `System.out.println((minutos/60) + " horas e " + (minutos%60) + " minutos");`

Comment: Acredito que a ideia de formatar km seja parecida com a acima. Claro que pode usar formatter para melhor exibição também.

Comment: Obrigado, vou aplicar ao meu problema

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uma solução direta e simples seria simplesmente adicionar um `f` de float em um dos operandos:

```
System.out.println("Distância em km = "+(metros/1000f));
```

e para horas, basta obter as horas dividindo por 60 e os minutos pegando o módulo da divisão por 60:

```
System.out.println((minutos/60) + " horas e " + (minutos%60) + " minutos");
```

Conforme sugestão do [@Zini](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/61434/zini), também pode-se formatar o número de casas decimais utilizando `printf`:

```
    System.out.println(String.format("Distância em km c/ duas casas decimais = %.2f", (metros/1000f)));
```

No exemplo acima, irá exibir até duas casas.

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/B69iyi).

Comment: Use dessa forma para controlar o número de casas da divisão: System.out.println(String.format("Distância em km = %.2f", (3/1000f)));

Comment: @Zini obrigado :) atualizado na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas para acrescentar algo que não foi citado nas outras respostas, você poderia utilizar o operador de coerção unária `(cast)` para obter o resultado com casas decimais sem precisar criar uma variável específica.

```
System.out.println("Distância em km = "+ (float)metros/1000);
```

ou

```
System.out.println("Distância em km = "+ (double)metros/1000);
```

Nos dois casos o valor retornado é "1,5".