# TextView não está exibindo números decimais de uma variável do tipo long!

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

Criei 3 **TextViews** e 2 variáveis do tipo **long**.

2 das TextViews exibirão as duas variáveis long em separado, já a última exibe o resultado de uma divisão da primeira (**n01**) variável long pela segunda (**n02**). => **n01/n02**

**MainActivity:**

```js
package genesysgeneration.along;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvN01, tvN02, tvResult;
    private long n01, n02;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvN01=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvN01);
        tvN02=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvN02);
        tvResult=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

        n01=17;
        n02=3;

        tvN01.setText(String.valueOf(n01));
        tvN02.setText(String.valueOf(n02));
        tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(n01/n02));


    }
}
```

O problema é quando o tvResult (o TextView que foi utilizado para exibir a divisão de **n01/n02**) tem de exibir um resultado **decimal/fracionário**... No caso acima por exemplo, o tvResult exibe o valor 5 como resultado, quando devia ser 5 e uns quebrados...

Como faço para exibir os **"quebradinhos"** e como limitar a quantidade de números depois da vírgula?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174459/formatar-resultado-de-uma-divis%C3%A3o-de-inteiros/174460

Comment: o tipo `long` representa números inteiros. `long` nunca tem decimais. Por isso as respostas dos colegas exigem a conversão de tipo.

Comment: Vlw man, de fato ficou bem mais fácil mudando para double, não queria, mas simplificou muito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça um cast do `n02` para `float`:

```
tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(n01 / (float) n02));
```

Com um número limitado de casas decimais:

```
// altere 2 em "%.2f" para a quantidade de casas decimais
tvResult.setText(String.format("%.2f", n01 / (float) n02));
```

Comment: VLW!!! mas eu limito a quantidade dos número depois da vírgula de qual forma?

Comment: altere o 2 em "%.2f" para a quantidade de casas decimais depois da vírgula

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), ou fazer desta forma abaixo, no qual `2f` significa que quer 2 casas depois da vírgula. Veja:

```
String.format("%.2f", number);
```

Adaptando

```
long valor = n01 /n02;
tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", valor)));
```